# Electricity through water

Tags: electricity, water, earth

If you're sat in a body of water through with an electric current runs, can you survive if you create an earth wire to lead the electricity away from you?

Comment: You can model it as a circuit , even if thats the path where current mostly flows , there is conductive material between the current and you , so there will definitely be some current that flows towards you

Comment: How would the wire “lead the electricity away from you”? Where would you connect it?

Answer (score 0):

By earth wire, I suppose you mean the ground which normally directs current away which makes the amount of electricity that reaches where you don't what it to reach zero or sometimes almost zero. However, when you are in water, electricity operates slightly differently, and I am assuming the wire is exposed and so if it then some of the electricity could definitely travel into the wire and not cause as much harm, but at the same time some of the electric current could travel through the water and hit the person because water has ions, which makes it conductive. Also assuming the ground wire is exposed, a lot of that electricity can easily transfer outside the wire making it far less effective as opposed to when the ground wire is in air.

So all in all, the water acts as a medium with ions which makes it act like a bunch of wires in a sense which connect from the ground wire into the person and making the ground far less effective. An analogy could be having the ground wire separate into two separate wires and a person touching one wire of the ground wire which has the same effect of getting hit by the electricity because the electrons are redirected from the original source into the wire and to the end of the wire.

Comment: The water basically makes the ground wire act as if it has connections all over the water which can allow it transmit a good portion of that all over the water.